# Android Kotlin StateFlow - Does not emit new Value with value.copy()

Tags: android, kotlin, copy, kotlin-stateflow

I'm trying to figure out what the best practice is in ViewModel. StateFlow, LiveData or ComposeState. Now I have come across something that I can't explain.

Activity:

```
val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

setContent {
      val randomAdmin by viewModel.randomAdmin.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

      Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
      Text(text = "Random Admin: ${randomAdmin.name} / ${randomAdmin.age}")
      BasicButton("ChangeAnyAdmib"){
        viewModel.changeRandomAdmin()
      }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _randomAdmin = MutableStateFlow( Admin("Peter",0) )
    val randomAdmin = _randomAdmin.asStateFlow()


    fun changeRandomAdmin() {
        _randomAdmin.value = _randomAdmin.value.copy(name = "Hans")
    }

}
```

Works well. The new admin will be emited.
But when I change the ViewModel function code (see below), the new admin will not be emitted. Why?
I have the same issue with LiveData & MutableState. It will not emited. Strangely enough, the reference is the same.

```
    fun changeRandomAdmin() {
        _randomAdmin.value.name = "Hans"
        val oldValue = _randomAdmin.value
        _randomAdmin.value = _randomAdmin.value.copy()
        Log.d("ViewModelTest" , "Same Object: " + (oldValue === _randomAdmin.value).toString()) // true
    }
```

But when I use this code (see below) the reference is not the same, but it should.
Unfortunately the object is still not emitted

```
    fun changeRandomAdmin() {
        _randomAdmin.value.name = "Hans"
        val oldValue = _randomAdmin.value.copy()
        _randomAdmin.value = oldValue
        Log.d("ViewModelTest" , "Same Object: " + (oldValue === _randomAdmin.value).toString()) // false
    }
```

I no longer understand the world ;(

It should emit the new object, I thought.

Comment: In general, you can't mutate values from a StateFlow.  If you need to copy, then you need to copy first and then assign the new value second, not the other way around.  It will help if you make `Admin` immutable, so its properties are all vals instead of vars.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do:

```
fun changeRandomAdmin() {
    _randomAdmin.value = randomAdmin.value.copy(name = "Hans")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first `changeRandomAdmin` function you are setting a new instance of `Admin` by using the `copy` function. This triggers an emit as those two `Admin`s are not the same.

In the second and third `ChangeRandomAdmin` function you are not setting a new admin value directly to the `StateFlow`, but you mutate the existing one. This is not noticed by the `StateFlow`.

You have referential equality in the second `changeRandomAdmin` function for `oldValue` and `_randomAdmin.value`, because `_randomAdmin.value = _randomAdmin.value.copy()` has no effect, as the `StateFlow` checks for (structural) equality before emitting values, take a look at the [docs for StateFlows](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/) section
*Strong equality-based conflation*.